# tikzsymbol inside todonote

Tags: tikz-pgf, incompatibility, todonotes, tikzsymbols

1. What causes this?
2. How can this be fixed?

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{todonotes}
   \usepackage{tikzsymbols}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \begin{document}
   \lipsum[1-4]
   Good stuff.\todo{hello \dWinkey how are you?}
   \lipsum[5-8]
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

Comment: On the first run, everything is fine (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S3od.png), on the second run, I get this strange spacing too and a warning `Label pgfid3 multiply defined.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When both `tikzsymbols` and `todonotes` packages are loaded, the `\dWinkey` has unusual (erroneous?) height.  This appears to be a conflict between the `todonotes` and `tikzsymbols` packages?

So here, I load `tikzsymbols`, and save a typeset copy of `\dWinkey` in a box.  Then, I load `todonotes`.  Thereafter, I must use the boxed version of `\dWinkey`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newsavebox\Wbox
\savebox\Wbox{\dWinkey}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
Good stuff.\todo{hello \usebox\Wbox how are you?}
\lipsum[5-8]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a simpler usage syntax, since `\dWinkey` becomes useless after the `todonotes` package is loaded, one can redefine it, though it will not scale with font size changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newsavebox\Wbox
\savebox\Wbox{\dWinkey}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\def\dWinkey{\usebox\Wbox}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
Good stuff.\todo{hello \dWinkey how are you?}
\lipsum[5-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The weird thing is that according to the manual, the smileys are already typeset via savebox/usebox.  The package allows me to turn it off, in which case I get the same size box but with the smiley at the top and the text at the bottom.  How a savebox inside a savebox solves the problem is beyond me....

Comment: Funny you should mention that.  I am just reading up on `\unhbox` to see if I can extend the answer to capture subsequent font size changes.  So far, no luck, but it points out that `\unhbox` only unwraps the outermost box.  Perhaps it is tied up in that concept...

Comment: Even if one turns the package's usebox feature off then using a savebox still solves the problem.  Hmmm.   I've written to the author.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wrote to the author, who's working on a fix.  He noted that if one uses it first outside a todonote, then subsequent uses inside a todonote work as desired.....  Curiouser and curiouser.

Answer (score 3):

The package author has uploaded a new version of the package to ctan in which this issue is addressed.